# Unexpected end of JSON input - Plain JS

Tags: javascript, json

This is a test program as I'm learning to work with JSON and tokens.  The end point is Python Flask.  It seems to work fine, even what it displays in my page is fine, only I see the error in the console.

**Code:**

```
function encodeUser(user, password) {
   var token = user + ":" + password;
   var hash = btoa(token);
   return "Basic " + hash;
}

function login(resultElement) {
    result = document.getElementById(resultElement)
    u = document.getElementById("email").value;
    p = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = config_baseurl + "/login"
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", encodeUser(u, p)); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       txt = this.responseText;
       respJson = JSON.parse(txt);
       result.innerHTML = 'response: ' + txt + '<br><br>token: ' + respJson.token;
    };
     xhr.send();
}
```

**The results display as expected in my page:**

response: { "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiI3ODIxMDVjNi00ZWRhLTQyMjMtYmQ2Yy1hMDhmMzgzNWExZmUiLCJleHAiOjE2MzQ5MjA4NDR9.iHJQf3qGOJlWcSuw-itTk-IirUGUAnmtNKyUXBDnI0Y" }

token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiI3ODIxMDVjNi00ZWRhLTQyMjMtYmQ2Yy1hMDhmMzgzNWExZmUiLCJleHAiOjE2MzQ5MjA4NDR9.iHJQf3qGOJlWcSuw-itTk-IirUGUAnmtNKyUXBDnI0Y

**The console shows this error**

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (example.js:36)

Comment: `this.responseText` should be `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: @zhulien - I made that change and had the same results.

Comment: `console.log()` the `responseText`. Maybe you have some `/r/n` / `/n` artifacts at the end.

Comment: added the following lines after result.innerHTML....

       console.log('txt: ' + txt);
       console.log('just the token: ' + respJson.token);

Comment: Got the same error then the following output in the log:  

'''
txt: {
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiI3ODIxMDVjNi00ZWRhLTQyMjMtYmQ2Yy1hMDhmMzgzNWExZmUiLCJleHAiOjE2MzQ5MzI3OTF9.ZntmMGnMsnlC0Z2V3GJcvoYH_g-lN1JqaR0tvanxz7M"
}

example.js:38 just the token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiI3ODIxMDVjNi00ZWRhLTQyMjMtYmQ2Yy1hMDhmMzgzNWExZmUiLCJleHAiOjE2MzQ5MzI3OTF9.ZntmMGnMsnlC0Z2V3GJcvoYH_g-lN1JqaR0tvanxz7M

Comment: Interestingly, I got the output twice (but did not get the error twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with fetch / promises? Timing stuff with XMLHttpRequest is difficult. I suspect that responseText doesn't actually have a value at the time you are decoding the JSON

Something like this

```
function encodeUser(user, password) {
    const token = user + ":" + password;
    const encoded = btoa(token); // NOTE: Base64 is not hashing!
    return "Basic " + encoded;
}

function login(resultElement) {
    const result = document.getElementById(resultElement);
    const u = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const p = document.getElementById("password").value;

    const url = config_baseurl + "/login";
    const init = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: encodeUser(u, p),
        },
    };

    fetch(url, init)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log({ data });
            result.innerText = data.token;
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for your help.  It always bugs me when things seem to work, but still log errors.  Also, very readable formatting, gentle corrections, and straight forward explanation.